# Send Email when node has been updated with specific term/selection

Tags: 7, emails, rules

I am looking for a way to configure a Drupal site to automatically send an email when a certain selection is made. Specifically, I have a content type with a field that presents the option 'In Progress' or 'Complete', and I would like to trigger an email when someone marks an instance of the content type as 'Complete.'

Not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rules **Add Condition** >> Data Comparison >> node:field-[name of your field goes here]

Add Action >> Send Mail